# Python Decorator Type Error in a recursive problem

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, python-decorators, recurrence

When I am using the decorator to writte the recursive fibonacci function with the momoization tehnique like:

```
from functools import lru_cache
init1 = {0:1,1:1}

@lru_cache(maxsize=10000)
def fib(n, init=init1):
  if n in init.keys():
    return init[n]
  else:
    return fib(n-1,init)+fib(n-2,init)
```

and run fib(5,init1), the following error is printed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I handle it?
PS.: I want to define many initial conditions thats why I dont incorporate the init1 variable inside the function scope.

Comment: Do you know why since dict is mutable and thus not hashable, @functools.lru_cache can't decorate my function? By the way, surely your link solves my problem but I am still implementing the solution.

Comment: In this question it seems like you're half way between using `lru_cache` for your memoization and doing it yourself with a mutable default argument. You probably don't need both!

Comment: I am working with this example again and I realize that even when I define frozendict to use the lru_cache I can not update init1 to avoid recomputing same keys if I re run the programme. I dont understand the advateges of using lru_cache....

Comment: When you say "re run the programme" do you mean the whole thing from scratch, or just calling the function again from within the same session? Because no simple caching approach is going to handle runs in separate sessions, you need serialization for that.

Comment: I mean call the function again with different n, (sorry for
 my ambiguous expression, I am newbie). Example: I run fib(10, init1), latter I run fib(20, init1) but no need to compute any fibonacci sequence up 10 should be necessary. I expected that after runing fib(10,init1), the dic init1 hold the information of all the fib numbers up to step 10. I can do that with the normal dic just adding a line like: init1[n]= fib(n-1,init)+fib(n-2,init), but It seems to be not possible to do that with frozen dicts...

Comment: Using `lru_cache`, the dictionary you pass as an argument won't be updated. Just pass the same dictionary (or use the default for both calls) and it should do the caching for you in the background.